# Python 3 - Urllib3 read internet radio metadata

Tags: python, audio-streaming, shoutcast, urllib3

How can I read information about playing song using urllib3? Which headers should I use?

```
import urllib3 
http = urllib3.PoolManager()
response = http.request("GET", "http://pool.cdn.lagardere.cz/fm-evropa2-128", headers={
        'User-Agent': 'User-Agent: VLC/2.0.5 LibVLC/2.0.5',
        'Icy-MetaData': '1',
        'Range': 'bytes=0-',
    })
print(response.data)
```

I tried this. But it stucks at sending request. Can anyone help me? Thanks for answers.

Comment: Maybe this helps http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/

Comment: Thanks it looks good!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code returns all the *header data* of the given stream. Unfortunately I was not able to obtain song names this way.

```
import requests

url = 'http://pool.cdn.lagardere.cz/fm-evropa2-128'

def print_url(r, *args, **kwargs):
    print(r.headers)

requests.get(url, hooks=dict(response=print_url))
```

**Output is as follows:**

```
{'icy-description': 'Evropa 2', 'Via': '1.1 s670-6.noc.rwth-aachen.de:80 (Cisco-WSA/8.8.0-085)', 'icy-genre': 'Various', 'icy-url': 'http://www.evropa2.cz', 'icy-pub': '0', 'ice-audio-info': 'ice-samplerate=44100;ice-bitrate=128;ice-channels=2', 'Date': 'Fri, 29 Jan 2016 17:24:20 GMT', 'icy-br': '128, 128', 'Content-Type': 'audio/mpeg', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'icy-name': 'Evropa 2', 'Server': 'Icecast 2.3.2', 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'}
```